# jetstream not updating features (on config/jetstream.php)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-jetstream

I am following a jetstream tutorial and in it says that, in order to add some jetstream features, you should uncomment some lines and it should update automatically. in this part of jetstream.php:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Features
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some of Jetstream's features are optional. You may disable the features
| by removing them from this array. You're free to only remove some of
| these features or you can even remove all of these if you need to.
|
*/

'features' => [
    Features::termsAndPrivacyPolicy(),
    Features::profilePhotos(),
    Features::api(),
    Features::teams(['invitations' => true]),
    Features::accountDeletion(),
],
```

As you can see, I have uncommented everything and yet my login page of jetstream does not update accordingly. the features such as profilephoto are not there. what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

I think every feature requires some steps after, for example the  **Features::profilePhotos()** requires to run:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

this creates a symbolic link in you app to store those files.

Check the details required for each feature in the documentation, you can start with the [Profile Photo](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/profile-management.html#enabling-profile-photos).

Comment: thats the writing on the wall for me then, there's something wrong with my jetstream install.

Comment: Did you try to activate the Profile Photo? What happened?

Comment: I followed the steps in the docs and it did nothing. not even with a migration. there's something wrong with my install

Comment: Did you do for all features or just for the Profile Photo?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, with a laravel jetStrean project.
To make the features appear, i had to clean the memory caching:
Here are the commands that solved my problem:

> php artisan cache:clear
> php artisan view:cache 
> php artisan optimize:clear

Past them into your terminal.
Enjoy